# Need help tracking down a specific website (to identify Spotify account)

Tags: web-services, spotify, penetration-testing

I stumbled across a website a while back where it showed the privacy repercussions of logging in to Spotify using the web version. I believe it used JavaScript but I can't be too sure. Anyway, this unrelated website was able to display my Spotify username despite me not authorizing anything. If I remember correctly, it also had slots for other services that I didn't use so it couldn't show my username there.

But what I'm interested in learning about is how it managed to get my Spotify username. Not because I plan to use the method but out of curiosity with how the whole thing works. When I found out about that page/site awhile back, it spooked me enough that I started using a different browser profile specifically for Spotify going forward because of it but I never got around to digging deeper into how it actually did what it did.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies save your an `access token` for Spotify account after to success login of Spotify.

Next time, if open your browser go to

```
https://open.spotify.com/
```

It's java-script to access  from your PC's cookies,
call this API with cookies an `access token`, get your information.

Then display your user name in the web page.

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/me
```

[image]

If I copy from my Chrome browser the access-token and API URL,
Then access by Postman.

I can get the my user name.

[image]

Each browser has own location to save a cookies,
if you never login before other browser, will not pick up your information.

I did not login before by Firefox.
This is screen of login.
[image]

Comment: But it's a different website so how can it access Spotify's cookies? Isn't cookie access restricted to the same domain?

Comment: Which web site?

Comment: Anyone know to location Spotify's cookies can access the access-token and using it like my Postman I did it. Spotify warning the legal issues.
https://www.spotify.com/us/legal/cookies-policy/

Comment: I'm talking about the site I saw in the past, how can it access cookies from a different domain (open.spotify.com)?